# How much effort can be caused linguistically to reintroduce a writing system to a language?

Tags: written-language, language-revival

Are there any experiences of reintroducing a writing system to a language? If so, what may be the challenges since the spoken language and the writing system may have been diverged?

Comment: I think there are people wanting Mongolian script to be used for Mongolian once more instead of Cyrillic, and possibly even for Manchu. I also wonder if Cherokee is written much these days and if so, whether it's usually written in its native script or not.

Comment: Yes, you got the point. There are people trying to reintroduce Mongolian script for Mongol, Daur and Manchu languages. When you look at spoken Mongolian and Mongolian script, you may notice diversion between them. However, it's also possible that there always have been diversion and it's not a problem - I mean examine written English and spoken English. Right?

Comment: I think you should put more effort into expanding your question, I think it's too brief for people to necessarily get what it is you're asking. I'm glad I did and I await the answers but I don't know myself.

Comment: You could look at the efforts in Montenegro, where new characters have been introduced to both the Latin and Cyrillic alphabets for the Montenegrin Language. The characters Ś and Ź (Cyrillic: С́ and З́) have been added, along with Đ, to better represent the phonetic distinctions in the language (though partly to demonstrate a distinctness between the new language and with Serbian!)

Comment: @DangerFourpence I think the Montenegrin example is a different kind of practice: branching out few different variants in order to differentiate a language.

Comment: Do you mean such as the re-introduction of the Latin alphabet to the Moldovan language?

Comment: Dagvadorj, do you really want the Mongolian script to be reintroduced? I understand why, but a lot of GUIs won't support a vertical script.

Comment: One can take any script and adapt it to fit any language. It’s unwise to try to map the conventions used for one script 1:1 onto another (*transliteration*), because that won’t take full advantage of the features that the new script offers. Alas, exactly that has been done several times when there was a switch, e.g. from roman to cyrillic or vice versa, and in digraphic societies (e.g. ex-Yugoslavia). It’s probably helpful if there’s a related language that is already written in the different script (Turkish:Turkmene, Romanian:Moldovan) – better take that as a guidance than any old convention.